# Convert string list to date list Python 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have a list of dates that python recognizes as `str`. I need to be able to work this as dates, to be able to add and subtract days. The dates are of the form "29-Jun-2017"

How can I have a date list instead of a String list?

Answer (score 1):

[`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) converts string to `datetime` object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('29-Jun-2017', '%d-%b-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 0, 0)
```

Then, [`datetime.datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) will return `date` object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('29-Jun-2017', '%d-%b-%Y').date()
datetime.date(2017, 6, 29)
```

---

See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for other format codes.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow module makes this type of calculation with dates especially easy.

Here I create a short list of date strings which I convert to arrow dates. Having displayed these dates I use the `replace` method to subtract two days from each date, creating a new list. Then I format this result for display.

```
>>> import arrow
>>> data = [ '01-Jan-2017', '31-Dec-2017' ]
>>> data_as_dates = [ arrow.get(_, 'DD-MMM-YYYY') for _ in data]
>>> data_as_dates 
[<Arrow [2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2017-12-31T00:00:00+00:00]>]
>>> two_days_earlier = [ _.replace(days=-2) for _ in data_as_dates ]
>>> [_.format('YYYY MMMM DD') for _ in two_days_earlier]
['2016 December 30', '2017 December 29']
```

The dates contained in arrow objects are available as conventional Python dates suitable for use with datetime, for instance.

Comment: sir, i have dates in a list of string formats like this lst_one = ['2016-9-29', '2016-9-28', '2016-9-27']. how will I strip them?                                                                                             this is what I need: ```Highest: 45C on June 23
Lowest: 01C on December 22
Humid: 95% on August 14``` .                          i am getting data from CSV files

Comment: @imhamza3333: You would follow a similar coding pattern.

>>> import arrow
>>> lst_one = ['2016-9-29', '2016-9-28', '2016-9-27']
>>> lst_one_in_arrow_form = [arrow.get(_, 'YYYY-M-DD') for _ in lst_one]
>>> [_.format('MMMM DD') for _ in lst_one_in_arrow_form]
>['September 29', 'September 28', 'September 27']